# Get rid of the frames but keep the same working method

Tags: html, transform, frames

Almost ten years ago, I built this website:
http://fleets.alltrams.com/

It is built with frames. So, now I want to improve it by avoiding working with frames, like divs, iframes and maybe some PHP. The things is that I want to keep the working method of the website intact. It's important that each city/item from the menu will get a separate page and URL path. But it's still important that the scrolling position of the menu stays the same, after clicking on one of the cities/items (and loading the page that belongs to it). By working with pages for each city/item, a "new" page will be loaded and the scrolling position of the menu will of course be positioned to the top again... So, what structure could I use to get done as described?

Comment: Use a PHP include for the header

Comment: @APAD1 — See the last sentence of the question.